# How to update Strava activities using API in python?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, put, strava

I'm trying to update my Strava activities using python. I'm using the requests module to send GET, POST, and PUT requests.
I am trying to update my activity using put but I keep on getting this error

```
{'errors': [{'code': 'not found', 'field': '', 'resource': 'Activity'}],'message': 'Resource Not Found'}
```

I have the write access token and I created a dictionary with the things I want to update but I still keep on getting this return.
This is the line of code I'm using to try and update the activity

```
updateActivty = requests.put(updatableActivity_url, headers=write_header, data=changeDescription, verify=False).json()
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?
(Sorry if I formatted this question bad. It's my first post on stack overflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It turns out I was creating separate access tokens one with scope activity:write and another with scope activity:read. I had to create an access token with both scope activity:write and activity:read. It lets me update activities now

Answer (score 0):

I pulled this from the [docs](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Activities-updateActivityById), have you tried doing something similar?

```py
from __future__ import print_statement
import time
import swagger_client
from swagger_client.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

# Configure OAuth2 access token for authorization: strava_oauth
swagger_client.configuration.access_token = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'

# create an instance of the API class
api_instance = swagger_client.ActivitiesApi()
id = 789 # Long | The identifier of the activity.
body =  # UpdatableActivity |  (optional)

try: 
    # Update Activity
    api_response = api_instance.updateActivityById(id, body=body)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling ActivitiesApi->updateActivityById: %s\n" % e)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried using that but the problem was actually the access token I was using didn't have the right scopes. I figured it out.